# how to detect pdf links and replace with embed code using php?

Tags: php, pdf, preg-replace, embed

how to detect pdf links using php and add pdf embed code using preg_replace to show the pdf as part of the page?

tested this embed code but not working

```
<OBJECT data="YourFile.pdf" TYPE="application/vnd.adobe.pdfxml" TITLE="SamplePdf" 
WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=100>
    <a href="YourFile.pdf">shree</a> 
</object>
```

Comment: link example  http://example.com/file.pdf

Comment: found working embed code ``` <embed src="http://example.com/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" /> ```